# How to show Python Tkinter GUI on local display from Docker

Tags: python, docker, tkinter

I would ask for help with the Python GUI (Tkinter) on Docker Container that I would like to display on the local display.

Could anyone describe me the step by step procedure:

- creating a docker containerhow the docker gui could then be displayed on the local display
- Dockefile
- i use windows 10 on local pc
- Tkinter script:

```
from tkinter import *
glavno_okno = Tk()
glavno_okno.title("Some Text")
glavno_okno.state('normal')
```

Tnx for help...

Answer (score 0):

You would need access the display which is a huge pain. [This](https://medium.com/dot-debug/running-chrome-in-a-docker-container-a55e7f4da4a8) is how they do it when running Chrome on a container.